# How to Set frame rate in RTSPserver

Tags: streaming, live, rtsp, live555

I have created RTSPServer application using Live555. In this application 
server receives live stream from a Live media Streamer application
which in turn get stream from digital camera.

Is there any way to set frame rate at server side so that my server
can stream with variable frame rate as per receivers requirement?

Answer (score 1):

No, the framerate is dependent on the incoming source i.e. in your case the camera. Also, how would you handle multiple receivers since each receiver will likely have different requirements?

Comment: Actually my receiver connecting server by TCP connection and receiving streaming using RTSP over TCP.
In our LAN it works perfect but when I tried to do same thing from external LAN.my receiver facing packets loss,it might be due to network conjunction. I have opened particular port 
for external receiver by adding port in my firewall. but still streaming is very slow.
that's why I'm thinking of reducing frame-rate at server end. so that we can receive packets faithfully.
I'm not sure whether it work for me I'm new to networking and streaming.

Comment: You can of course reduce the framerate to see what happens, but the easiest way to do this is likely by configuring the camera. You could also reduce the resolution for testing purposes. In the end, if you don't have the bandwidth, you can't stream TCP or UDP. There are mechanisms such as you describe for adaptive streaming, but you would most likely have implement the adaptation mechanism yourself e.g. if you use a video codec that supports temporal scalability, you could encode the stream and with some effort, you could drop certain frames if you notice that TCP send buffer is filling up.